# One of Composite primary key as Foreign key Mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I Have two Tables.

```
CREATE TABLE One(
    Oneid int,
    Twoid int,
    data char(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(Oneid,Twoid) )
```

Table One is Oneid and Twoid as primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE Two(
    Twoid int,
    data char(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(Twoid) )
```

And I want to One.Twoid is foreign key for Table Two.
How to solve it.
Thank a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the constraint in the `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Two(
    Twoid int,
    data char(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (Twoid));

CREATE TABLE One(
    Oneid int,
    Twoid int,
    data char(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (Oneid,Twoid),
    FOREIGN KEY (Twoid) REFERENCES Two(Twoid)); -- <== here
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8a127).

Or use `ALTER TABLE` if your tables already exist:

```
ALTER TABLE One
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Twoid FOREIGN KEY (Twoid) REFERENCES Two (Twoid);
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a55ed).