# Setting Foreign Key restraints on Junction table with a compound primary key

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, junction-table

I have a junction table that stores the relationship between tests and the questions in the tests, with `testFK` and `questionFK` set as a compound primary key to prevent duplicate entries.

**Junction Table:**

```
    +--------+------------+
    | testFK | questionFK |
    +--------+------------+
    |    7   |      1     |
    +--------+------------+
    |    7   |      2     |
    +--------+------------+
    |    7   |      3     |
    +--------+------------+
    |    8   |      4     |
    +--------+------------+
    |    8   |      5     |
    +--------+------------+
    |    8   |      6     |
    +--------+------------+
```

**What I want to do:**

Upon deleting `testID` from the `test table`, I would like all the rows with `testFK=8` from the `Junction Table` to be deleted as well.

**The Problem:**

phpmyadmin won't let me set `testFK` as a `foreign key` for `testID` from the `test table`.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Thanks for any input!

**UPDATE:**
Create Code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `junc_test_question` (
  `testFK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `questionFK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ordinal` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`testFK`,`questionFK`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: It might be this answers it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184538/one-of-composite-primary-key-as-foreign-key-mysql

Comment: @MortenSickel I get the same error when I try this: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_assess`.`#sql-2510_69`, CONSTRAINT `testFK` FOREIGN KEY (`testFK`) REFERENCES `test` (`testID`))

Comment: post your create table code please

Comment: you can create trigger for that

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TRIGGER remove_test_table
GO
CREATE TRIGGER remove_test_table
FOR DELETE
AS 
DELETE FROM test_table WHERE testFK IN (SELECT testFK FROM deleted);
GO
```

Comment: Please explain how your code provides a solution to the question. This helps the OP understand and apply your code and also helps future searchers.

Comment: when entry delete remove_test_table its remove all the entry which are connected with  test_table